# ¿Matriz como atributo?

Tags: c++, dev-c++, fórmulas-de-matriz

estoy intentando crear un tablero, con distintas dimensiones, es decir, 3 x 3, 4 x 4 y 5 x 5

El problema es que no se si esta declarado bien la parte de los atributos de mi clase tablero. Me pueden decir si esta bien ?
Por otro lado, estaba pensando en usar un constructor para determinar el tamaño de mi tablero, es decir, pasarle parámetros y crear una matriz, pero cuando la inicializo hay datos donde no deben estar. ¿Saben donde esta el problema o estoy haciendo mal todo?

Esta es el codigo de la clase tablero:

```
    #ifndef TABLERO_H
    #define TABLERO_H

    const int row = 1;
    const int col = 1;

class Tablero
{

    private: 
    int c;
    int f;
    int mat [col][row];

    public:
    Tablero ();
    Tablero (int pC, int pF);
    void mostrarT ();
    void setN (int pA, int pB, int pC, int pD);
    ~Tablero (); 
};


    Tablero::Tablero ()
{
    c = 5;
    f = 4;

    for (int i = 0; i < c; i ++ )
        for (int j = 0; j < f; j ++)
            mat [i][j] = 0;

    mat [3][1] = 1;

}
```

**La implementacion es la siguiente:**

```
Tablero::Tablero(int pC, int pF)
{
    c = pC;
    f = pF;

    for (int i = 0; i < c; i ++ )
        for (int j = 0; j < f; j ++)
            mat [i][j] = 0;

    mat [3][1] = 2;


}

Tablero::~Tablero()
{

}


void Tablero::mostrarT ()
{
    cout << "---------------------------" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < f; j++){
            cout << mat [i] [j] << "  ";
           }
        cout << endl;
        }


 } 

 void Tablero::setN (int pA, int pB, int pC, int pD)
 {  
    int r;

    r = rand () % (c-1);

    cout  << r << "<<<" << endl;

    while (r == 0 || r == 2 || r == 3 || r == 5 || r == 6 || r == 8)
    {
        r = 0 + rand () % (c-1);
        cout << r << "<<<";
    }

    cout  << r << "<<<" << endl;

    cout << pA << "<<---";

 }
```

y el main

```
int main() {
srand (time (NULL));

/*Ficha x;
x.mostrar();
Ficha y;
y.mostrar();*/

Tablero w;
w.mostrarT();

Tablero a (5, 4);
a.mostrarT();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cuando usas formaciones<sup>1</sup>, el tamaño debe ser conocido en tiempo de compilación o debes usar memoria dinámica; así que tu aproximación no es válida.

Una posible solución para *usar un constructor para determinar el tamaño del tablero* es, como he mencionado, usar memoria dinámica, para ello tu `Tablero::mat` deberá ser un doble puntero:

```
class Tablero
{
    int columnas;
    int filas;
    int **matriz;

public:
    Tablero ();
    Tablero (int pColumnas, int pFilas);
    void mostrarT ();
    void setN (int pA, int pB, int pC, int pD);
    ~Tablero (); 
};

Tablero::Tablero (int pColumnas, int pFilas) :
    columnas{pColumnas},
    filas{pFilas}
{
    matriz = new int*[pFilas];
    for (int indice = 0; indice < pFilas; ++indice)
        matriz[indice] = new int[pColumnas]{};
}
```

En la propuesta anterior he hecho los siguientes cambios:

1. Eliminada la etiqueta `private` en la clase, por redundante: La visibilidad por defecto de las clases ya es privada.
2. Asignados nombres autoexplicativos a las variables: Los nombres de una sola letra no explican nada del objetivo ni función de las variables; el nombre de una variable debería permitir saber de un vistazo su cometido, haciendo que el código sea menos propenso a errores y haciendo que sea más fácil de leer y entender, cosa que cualquier persona que trabaje contigo (incluso tu yo futuro) agradecerá mucho.
3. El miembro `Tablero::matriz` ha pasado a ser un puntero a puntero a entero, permitiendo la creación de una matriz bidimensional en tiempo de ejecución. Al añadir las llaves vacías al crear las filas (`new int[pColumnas]{}`), el compilador inicializará a 0 todos los elementos.
4. Las variables miembro `Tablero:columnas` y `Tablero:filas` se inicializan en la lista de inicialización del constructor, no en el cuerpo.

Esta propuesta cumple con tus objetivos, pero no es práctica; no hay garantía de que las filas estén anexas en memoria, lo cuál puede dar problemas de rendimiento. Podrías crear la matriz como un arreglo unidimensional y tratarlo como bidimensional:

```
class Tablero
{
    int columnas;
    int filas;
    int *matriz;

public:
    Tablero ();
    Tablero (int pColumnas, int pFilas);
    void mostrarT ();
    void setN (int pA, int pB, int pC, int pD);
    ~Tablero (); 
};

Tablero::Tablero (int pColumnas, int pFilas) :
    columnas{pColumnas},
    filas{pFilas}
{
    matriz = new int[pColumnas * pFilas]{};
}
```

Con la propuesta anterior, asignar un valor a la fila `y` en la columna `x`, se haría de la siguiente manera:

```
matriz[(y * columnas) + x] = valor;
```

Y para obtener el valor de la fila `y` en la columna `x` se haría de la siguiente manera:

```
valor = matriz[(y * filas) + x];
```

Puedes olvidarte de la gestión de memoria y obtener los mismos resultados que la propuesta anterior si cambias `Tablero::matriz` por un `std::vector`:

```
class Tablero
{
    int columnas;
    int filas;
    std::vector<int> matriz;

public:
    Tablero ();
    Tablero (int pColumnas, int pFilas);
    void mostrarT ();
    void setN (int pA, int pB, int pC, int pD);
    ~Tablero (); 
};

Tablero::Tablero (int pColumnas, int pFilas) :
    columnas{pColumnas},
    filas{pFilas},
    matriz(pColumnas * pFilas, 0)
{
}
```

---

1. También conocidas como *arreglos* o en inglés *arrays*.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta ! Solo para estar claro, en el programa que yo hice, el problema es que la matriz, al ser estática, no se puede cambiar las dimensiones mediante el constructor, cierto ?

Comment: Otra cuestión, me salio el siguiente `[Warning] extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11` pero lo solucione cambiando las llaves por paréntesis en el constructor y por lo que leí hay diferentes modos de inicializar el constructor, necesariamente hay inicializar las variables miembros antes del cuerpo del constructor ? Perdón, soy nuevo en la plataforma y también si pregunto algo que es obvio, solo quiero estar seguro

Comment: @CristhianIvan efectivamente, la matriz de tamaño estático no puede cambiar de tamaño de manera dinámica (ni mediante constructor ni por ningún otro medio). La alarma que te está dando es por compilar con utilidades de C++11 sin haber indicado a tu compilador que lo haga. Añade a la orden de compilación los parámetros que te aconseja y la alarma desaparecerá.

Comment: Ahora tengo la siguiente duda, como asignaria el valor de "1" a toda la columna 0 ? Yo lo intente de la siguiente forma pero no funciona `void Tablero::setFormato ()
{
 for (int y = 0; y < filas; y ++){
      matriz[(y * filas) + 0] = 1;
 cout << "\n";
 
 }
 
}`

Comment: E incluso cambie `matriz[(y * filas) + 0]` por `matriz[(y * columnas) + 0]` pero cuando ejecuto el programa parece que la matriz no está bien definida

Comment: Lo conseguí :,) [enlace](http://prntscr.com/l6tzsq) este era el objetivo de la clase tablero, pero para asignar un valor use `matriz[(y * columnas) + x]` y para obtener un valor igual

Answer (score 4):

> Me pueden decir si esta bien ?

Dado que comentas que te da problemas la respuesta es obvia, no, no está bien.

> ¿Saben donde esta el problema o estoy haciendo mal todo?

Si quieres que el tablero tenga un tamaño dinámico (es decir, que pueda cambiar de una ejecución a otra), necesitas usar memoria dinámica... y tu estás usando un array de tamaño fijo. El problema no es ya que el array sea de tamaño fijo, sino que además tiene como dimensión 1x1. Es decir, cualquier tablero definido por el usuario tendrá un tamaño mayor y eso provoca problemas.

Me explico. En C++ no hay chequeos que verifiquen si intentas acceder a un elemento que no pertenece a tu memoria. De hacer esas comprobaciones se encarga, en algunos casos, el Sistema Operativo y no te gustaría que entrase en acción porque lo que suele hacer es matar tu aplicación para que no corrompa la memoria.

Así pues lo que tienes que hacer es usar memoria dinámica y en este punto tienes que tomar una decisión respecto al constructor por defecto:

- Lo eliminas, ya que lo suyo es saber qué tamaño va a tener el tablero. Esta opción es la más sencilla
- Preparas toda la clase para que detecte que el tablero no está inicializado.

Imaginemos que elegimos la primera opción, el código podría quedar así:

```
class Tablero
{
private: 
  int c;
  int f;
  int* mat;

public:
  Tablero (int pC, int pF);
  ~Tablero ();

  void mostrarT() const;
  int Get(int pC, int pF) const;
};

Tablero::Tablero(int pC, int pF)
  : c(pC),
    f(pF),
    mat(new int[Pc*Pf](0))
{
  std::fill_n(mat,c*f,0); 
}

Tablero::~Tablero()
{
  delete mat;
}

int Get(int pC, int pF) const
{
  return mat[pF*c+pC];
}

void Tablero::mostrarT() const
{
  cout << "---------------------------" << endl;

  for (int i = 0; i < f; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)
      cout << Get(i,j) << "  ";
    cout << '\n';
  }
}
```